# “unresolved import 'requests'” but code can still run (VSCode)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

the code can run and debug
but it shows"unresolved import 'requests'Python(unresolved-import)"
is there any other settings what i missed?

```py
import requests
import os
url = 'https://www.google.com'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
html = response.text
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))+'\\test.txt'
with open(path, 'w', encoding = 'gbk') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you had any progress on this?